# How to find all indexes of a list that are empty in Python

Tags: python, list, iterator, enumeration

I wanted to know if there is an easy way to find all indexes of a list that are empty.

```
mylist  = [ [1,2,3,4], [] , [1,2,3,4] , [] ]
```

---

`next((i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if not j),"no empty indexes found")` will return the first empty index of the list, but can I return all of them? It will default to  the string `"no empty indexes found"` if there is no empty indexes.

I want to append all the empty indexes to another list to use.

```
my_indexes_list.append(next((i for i, j in enumerate(self.list_of_colors) if not j),5))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the fact that empty sequences are false in a boolean context, together with a list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist  = [[1,2,3,4], [] , [1,2,3,4] , []]
>>> [i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if not x]
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x ==[] ]
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
empties[]
for s in mylist:
    is len(s) == 0
        empties.append(mylist.index(s))
```